# Inline divs with combined widths of 100% still break to next line on zoom

Tags: css, html, width

This has plagued me for so long, and I've only ever found solutions that reduce the issue, rather than eliminating them. Three divs of 33% width (so technically, not even 100% combined width) look just fine on my screen, but when zoomed in, the left-most div falls to the next line. Why is this?

Mind you, this is after eliminating white space in code. I use the `>` selector in CSS to set the font size of the containing div (that holds the other three) to zero, which achieves the same results as the uglier, less readable solutions of putting things on one line, or using HTML comments.

I shouldn't need to provide any example code. It's an issue in any set of inline-block divs set to percentage widths inside a containing div.

Comment: @Pete `Mind you, this is after eliminating white space in code.`

Answer (score 0):

It is happening just because of spaces between inline-block divs...

like Code

On above code browser counts a space between  and

So add css property to parent

```
.parent {
font-size:0px;
}
```

See difference between this fiddles
Your Problem http://jsfiddle.net/BS72X/1/

Nd here solution http://jsfiddle.net/BS72X/
Hope this helps you..

Comment: I've said this exact same thing in my question. The issue happens despite font-size:0; and that I already use it to reduce the effects of this issue. It does not eliminate the issue completely though.